# google map widgetsets compilation

Tags: gwt, vaadin, vaadin7

an error msg has been appeared : `Widgetset 'com.example.myWidgesett' does not contain implementation for com.vaadin.tapio.googlemaps.GoogleMap. Check its component connector's @Connect mapping, widgetsets GWT module description file and re-compile your widgetset.`
i added manualy `"<inherits name="com.vaadin.tapio.googlemaps.Widgetset" />"` i 've got this error : Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'
java.lang.NullPointerException.
note that i'm not use maven.
please advise as soon as possible.

Comment: How do you compile your widgetset when not using maven? Have you added the vaadin widgets to the compile task?

Comment: in the web.xml, i have added the below code : <init-param>
   <description>Application widgetset</description>
   <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
   <param-value>MyWidgetSet</param-value>
  </init-param> and i compile widgetset via vaadin

Comment: I think @AndréSchild wanted to know how you are [compiling the Vaadin widgetset](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/gwt/gwt-eclipse.html#gwt.eclipse.compiling), not how you're specifying it.

Comment: i have installed vaadin add on and compile it

Comment: What IDE do you use for this?

Comment: Eclipse java EE IDE for Web Developers

Comment: I sometimes had issues with Eclipse not publishing my updated resources, so if you're sure to have compiled the widgetset, try a _clean publishing_ from the _servers_ view, and also try clearing the browser's cache (or open an incognito window). **P.S.** you can use @username when writing comments, so the user gets notified.

Comment: i have done all these steps but i have got the same result